# How to set environment variables in R to use a conda environemnt

Tags: r, environment-variables, rstudio, conda

The `reticulate` package is supposed to enable conda environments within R. I can trivially show that it does not work.

```
balter@conda-test:~$ R
> library(reticulate)
> use_condaenv('dada2')
> library(dada2)
Error in library(dada2) : there is no package called ‘dada2’
>
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
balter@conda-test:~$ source activate dada2
(dada2) balter@conda-test:~$ R
> library(dada2)
Loading required package: Rcpp
Warning message:
package ‘Rcpp’ was built under R version 3.4.4
>
```

With RStudio Desktop, I can launch it within the conda environment. However, with RStudio Server I need to use the `.Rprofile` to set appropriate paths. I did the best I could think of, and it's working pretty well, but I'm still occasionally getting errors when I try to load or especially install new packages (using bioconda).

My most current and strange error is this:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  internet routines cannot be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/lib/R/modules//internet.so':
  /home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/lib/R/modules//../.././libk5crypto.so.3: symbol krb5int_utf8s_to_ucs2les version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference
>
```

I do NOT get this error when I start R without the `.Rprofile` that sets the environment variables listed below.

**R environment**

```
PATH                    /home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/bin:/home/lab/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PWD                     /home/balter/F1000_workflow/MicrobiomeWorkflow
R_ARCH
R_BROWSER               /usr/bin/open
R_BZIPCMD               /home/lab/conda/bin/bzip2
R_DOC_DIR               /home/lab/conda/lib/R/doc
R_GZIPCMD               /bin/gzip
R_HOME                  /home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/lib/R
R_INCLUDE_DIR           /home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/lib/R/include/
R_LIBS_SITE             /home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/lib/R/library/
R_LIBS_USER             /home/lab/conda/envs/dada2/lib/
```

Comment: When you run if you run `which R` before and after `source activate dada2`, do you get different paths? I'm guessing you are running different R executables. Calling `use_condaenv()` when you are already running R, isn't going to change which R is running. You can also run it both ways and compare the results of `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Were you ale to find any solution here? I'm trying to set the default conda environment for R so that I don't have call use_condaenv() at the top of all my files.